# I am receiving the following error on eliminatng dummy variable trap in multivarible linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, dummy-variable

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[: , :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,4].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,3])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray

# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
X=X[:, 1:]
```

---

Writing the above code I'm getting the following error.Can you please suggest the edit

```
File "<ipython-input-35-9ad621cd0c86>", line 13, in <module>
    X=X[:, 1:]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

You missed the '()' there.